# Grabbing most recent record per customer per week

Tags: sql, impala

I am trying to query a table and return the most recent combination of a customer choice grouped by the week. For example, here is the table:

```
(int)        (string)    (int)      (bigint)
Customer ID  Choice      Week       Inserted at
100          a, b, c     2      20171002
100          a, b        2      20171004
101          b, c, d     2      20171002
102          a, c, d     2      20171002
103          a, b, c     2      20171002
103          a, b, d     2      20171003
100          a, b, c, d  3      20171010
101          a, c, d     3      20171010
101          b, c, d     3      20171011
102          a, b        3      20171010
103          a, b, c     3      20171010
103          b, c, d     3      20171012
103          a, b, d     3      20171014
```

And this is the query I want to produce:

```
Customer ID  Choice         Week    Inserted at
100          a, b           2       20171004
101          b, c, d        2       20171002
102          a, c, d        2       20171002
103          a, b, d        2       20171003
100          a, b, c, d     3       20171010
101          b, c, d        3       20171011
102          a, b           3       20171010
103          a, b, d        3       20171014
```

A customer can only make changes to their choices once a day so I don’t have to worry about a customer making many changes in one day.

This is what i started with but its missing a lot of rows. Any feedback?

```
SELECT c.customer, c.combo, c.week, c.date
FROM tableCombos AS c
WHERE not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM tableCombos AS recent
                  WHERE recent.customer = c.customer
                  AND recent.date > c.date)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am working in Cloudera Impala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select tc.*
from (select tc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, week order by date desc) as seqnum
      from tableCombos tc
     ) tc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I want get maximum o date grouped by week and customer:

```
select customerId , week, max(insertedAt) as date
group by customerId , WEEK
```

after that I can join this dataset with the main table

```
SELECT c.customer, c.combo, c.week, c.date
FROM tableCombos AS c
join (select customerId , week, max(insertedAt) as date
group by customerId , WEEK) X 
on c.customerId = X.customerId 
                  and c.week = X.week 
                  and c.date = X.date
```